# How to define a variable inside $_GET in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

`<?php 
$var = "sub";
echo $_GET['{$var}'];
?>`

i want this working when i called mydomain.com?sub=hii .
is there any other way to make this work?
I want to use random $var value from my database.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to output the GET variable, or a random value from the database? What you show above will work when you replace the single quotes `'` by double ones `"`

Comment: ya that was correct and even working echo $_GET[$var];

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? You want $var to retrieve a random value from a table in your database?

Comment: Why would you have `echo $_GET['{$var}'];` instead of `echo $_GET[$var];`?

Answer (score 1):

In a cakePHP environment the url usually is

```
http://domain/controller/action?sub=hii
```

Why not just using the framework as it is intended to be used - and as its documented:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters

```
$sub = $this->request->query('sub');

echo $sub // prints "hii"
```

Assuming you are using a current version of CakePHP. Please always mention the version you are working with to get correct and appropriate answers!